# How to guarantee an ETH transaction makes it to mainnet

Tags: transactions, confirmations

Is there a library out there that handles the lifecycle of a transaction and ensures it up to a certain guarantee (1-12 confirmations, accepted, etc)?

How do developers handle this issue?  It seems to be from reading some of the articles that there are many scenarios that can throw off a trx.

Thank you : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With web3js you can broadcast a transaction and then use the `.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })` event (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) :

> "confirmation" returns confirmationNumber: Number, receipt: Object, latestBlockHash: String: Fired for every confirmation up to the 12th confirmation. Receives the confirmation number as the first and the receipt as the second argument. Fired from confirmation 0 on, which is the block where it’s mined.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
value: '1000000000000000'
}) 
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ 
console.log(receipt.status); //return true if the transaction succeeded, false if it was reverted by the EVM
console.log(confirmationNumber);
})
```